# map is not a function how to solve in react / typescript / redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk, tsx

I want to take an api data using typescript / react / redux_thunk and make a simple application using that data

here is my code:

```
type.tsx: 
       export interface Iproduct {
      id: number;
      title: string;
      price: number;
      description: string;
      category: string;
      image: string;
    }
```

Actions.ts

```
 import { Iproduct } from "../types/type";
     export const getProduct = () => (dispatch: any) => {
          axios
            .get<Iproduct[]>("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
            .then((res) => dispatch({ type: "GET_PRODUCT", payload: res.data }))
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
            });
        };
```

Reducer :

```
import { Iproduct } from "../types/type";

interface Iproducs {
  products: any[];
}

const INITALIZE_STATE: Iproducs = {
  products: [],
};

type Action = { type: string; payload: any[] };

export const reducer = (state = INITALIZE_STATE, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_PRODUCT":
      return { ...state, products: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

App.tsx :

```
 const state = useSelector((state: Iproduct[]) => state);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const [products, setproducts] = useState<Iproduct[]>([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getProduct());
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setproducts(state);
        products.forEach((e: Iproduct) => console.log(e));
      });
```

I want to map inside the data I received with useSelector in app.tsx file, but I'm getting an error

"TypeError: products.map is not a function"

I will be glad if you tell me where I even did it, I cannot solve such mistakes because I have just learned the typescript.

note: I use redux-thunk in the project

Comment: I don't see you calling `products.map` anywhere in the code..?

Comment: fwiw derived state from another state is an anti-pattern. here you are creating a react state from redux state, that's not good.

Answer (score 0):

You probably sent a different code but I think I understand. When the component is first loaded, it comes undefined because you did not make any requests and the products data did not change. The simplest way to solve this is by using

`state => (state.products || []).map(value => ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace below code in reducer

```
export const reducer = (state = INITALIZE_STATE, action: Action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
      case "GET_PRODUCT":
        return { ...state, products: [action.payload] };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```